# Парсинг сайта в java с помощью jsoup

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup

Решил написать простенькую телепрограмму  с использованием `jsoup`. Задача более чем скучная, но для меня новая ибо раньше с парсерами не работал. Прошу у Вас помощи не в написание кода, а  совета как работать с парсером, читал статьи, но они рассказывают только про заголовки  и т.п., а вот как например спарсить расписание с первого канала на [странице](http://tv.yandex.ru). И может быть вы считаете, что `jsoup` полная лажа посоветуйте другой.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ну, а в чём проблема?

1. [Загрузите документ](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url).
2. [Снавигируйте](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) к элементу, содержащему программы.
3. Тем же способом найдите нужные элементы данных.

Какие именно HTML-атрибуты вам нужны, устанавливается внимательным чтением исходника сайта, который вы собираетесь распарсить.

На сайте даже есть [простейший пример](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links) (без навигации, просто все ссылки).

Answer (score 10):

Есть 2 типа html/xml парсеров:

1. SAX парсер - парсит в потоковом режиме, на вход подается поток html/xml, в определенных местах срабатывают т.н. хэндлеры, то есть перехватчики, которые говорят "сейчас парсер наткнулся на такой-то элемент". В хэндлер обычно прогер вставляет свой код и делает свое дело
2. DOM парсер - засовывается весь источник, на выходе получаем дерево - иногда довольно сложное.

jsoup это разновидность DOM парсера, так что весь вопрос в том, чтобы правильно спозиционироваться в дереве полученном после парсинга - или выражаясь языком модели DOM в нодах. Это описываетс документацией jsoup API в пакете `org.jsoup.nodes`.

Заодно нелишним будет почитать про [DOM](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) это сразу направит мозги в нужном направлении.

Удачи.

Comment: случайно, прочитал ваш ответ, и на пол дня залип в чтении SAX парсеров. Не могу понять теперь, почему на практике я их не встречал, ведь по сути это быстрей и безопасней. Очень интересно, скоро узнаем, спасибо за этот ответ. ПОставил бы +50 если мог.

Answer (score 5):

Я это делаю так. Тоже первый раз :)
Пока не разобрался как красиво выводить то, что спарсил :(

```
    package sm.play.sportlife.ua;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    public static int dayOfTheWeek = 0;
    // благодоря этому классу мы будет разбирать данные на куски
    public Elements time, currentday;
    // то в чем будем хранить данные
    public ArrayList<String> timeList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> dayEventList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /** Запрос к нашему отдельному поток на выборку данных */
        new GetDataThread().execute();

        dayOfTheWeek = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
        if (dayOfTheWeek == 0) {
            dayOfTheWeek = 7;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "День недели :" + dayOfTheWeek);
    }

    /**
     * А вот и внутрений класс который делает запросы в отдельном потоке
     */

    public class GetDataThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private TableRow row;
        private TableLayout inflate;
        private TextView txtcol1, txtcol2;
        private String eventNames;

        // private ProgressDialog prog;

        /**
         * Метод выполняющий запрос в фоне, в версиях выше 4 андроида, запросы в
         * главном потоке выполнять нельзя, поэтому все что вам нужно выполнять
         * - выносите в отдельный поток
         */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            String myURL = "http://www.sportlife.ua/ru/services/schedule/14875";
            // класс который захватывает страницу
            Document doc;

            try { // определяем откуда будем скачивать данные

                doc = Jsoup
                        .connect(myURL)
                        .userAgent(
                                "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36")
                        .get(); // задаем с какого места парсить

                /**
                 * Выбираем содержимое рассписания по индексу столбца
                 * td:eq(Индекс)
                 */

                // Время занятий
                int k = 0;
                String link = "#shedule-content tr:gt(0) " + "td:eq(" + k + ")";
                time = doc.select(link);

                link = "#shedule-content tr:gt(0) " + "td:eq(" + dayOfTheWeek
                        + ")";
                currentday = doc.select(link);

                /**
                 * Чистим наши ArrayList для того что бы заполнить и в цикле
                 * захватываем все данные какие есть на странице
                 */
                timeList.clear();
                dayEventList.clear();

                for (Element times : time) {
                    if (times.className().equals("time-col")) {
                        timeList.add(times.text()); // Записываем в ArrayList
                                                    // время занятий
                    }
                }
                /**
                 * Для каждого event currentday из записываем в аррей лист
                 * события дня
                 */
                for (Element event : currentday) {

                    if (event.hasText() == true) {
                        Elements mEvents = Jsoup.parse(event.html()).select(
                                ".event-item-body");
                        /** Может быть несколько занятий на одно и тоже время */
                        int i = 0;
                        do {
                            Element textEvent = mEvents.get(i);
                            String tmpString = textEvent.text();

                            if (eventNames == null) {
                                eventNames = tmpString + "\n";
                            } else {
                                eventNames = eventNames + tmpString + "\n";

                            }

                            i++;

                        } while (i < mEvents.size());
                        /** События заносим в список */
                        dayEventList.add(eventNames);
                        eventNames = "";
                    } else
                        // dayEventList.add(titles.text());
                        dayEventList.add("");

                }
            } catch (IOException e)

            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // prog.setMessage("Соединяемся...");
            // prog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            /** ФОРМИРУЕМ ТАБЛИЦУ */

            inflate = (TableLayout) MainActivity.this
                    .findViewById(R.id.mytable);

            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < timeList.size()
                    || j < dayEventList.size();) {
                row = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
                txtcol1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                if (timeList.size() > i) {
                    if ((timeList.get(i) != null)) {
                        txtcol1.setText(timeList.get(i));
                        txtcol1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_rec);
                        // txtcol1.setTextColor(Color.rgb(245, 245, 220));
                        // txtcol1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
                        i++;
                    }
                } else {
                    txtcol1.setText("");
                }
                row.addView(txtcol1);

                txtcol2 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                if ((dayEventList.size() > j)) {
                    if (dayEventList.get(j) != null) {
                        txtcol2.setText(dayEventList.get(j));
                        txtcol2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_rec);
                        // txtcol2.setMaxLines(20);
                        j++;
                    }
                } else {
                    txtcol2.setText("");
                }
                this.row.addView(txtcol2);

                inflate.addView(row);

            }

            /** КОНЕЦ ФОРМИРОВАНИЯ ТАБЛИЦЫ */

            // super.onPostExecute(result);
            // prog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```