# регулярные выражения как заменить html тег

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
<a class="autor" href="/bookcard?book_id=851397">Ленин, В. И. (Ульянов, В. И.).</a><br>
```

Я хочу заменить тэги `<a class="autor" href="/bookcard?book_id=851397"></a>` на тег `<author> и </author>`, а так же тег `<br>`

Еще бы понять, как можно "вырвать" id=851397, который внутри тега, чтобы получилось `<id>851397</id>`

Comment: Вам поможет HTML-парсер для выбранного языка. Регулярными выражениями ничего "вырывать" и менять не стоит.

Comment: приводите более точно, что должно быть на выходе. А также возможные входные варианты. Ещё неплохо указать язык программирования и, если доступно, какую библиотеку регулярок будете использовать.

Comment: [Ленин  — жил, Ленин  — жив, Ленин  — будет жить!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Информация из этого вопроса может быть вам полезна:
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-html-%D0%B2-net

Comment: Я пишу парсер на java

Comment: @volkovsergey: А чем Вас не устраивает [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)?

Comment: Возьмите парсер и не морочьте себе (и нам) голову. _As I have answered in HTML-and-regex questions here so many times before, the use of regex will not allow you to consume HTML._ (c)

Answer (score 1):

```
(class="autor"\s.+id=(\d+).+)>(.*)(<\/a>)
```

смотри тут https://regex101.com/r/aK2aJ4/4

в итоге 4 переменные

```
1 - `class="autor" href="/bookcard?book_id=851397"`
2 - `851397`
3 - `Ленин, В. И. (Ульянов, В. И.).`
4 - `</a>`
```

Вам нужна 2 и 3

Comment: [А вот тут этот подход не сработает.](https://regex101.com/r/aK2aJ4/3)

Comment: Спасибо!
Я вырвал '<a class="autor" href="/bookcard?book_id=851397">' с помощью '<a class="autor" href="/bookcard.book_id=[0-9]+">' и легко заменил на нужный тег.
Теперь думаю, как вырвать из тега 'id=851397'

Comment: Ваш пример работает, но в моём случае (java) выводится строка полностью. Поэтому мне приходится успешно парсить второй раз эту строку выражением 'id=[0-9]+'
Мне нравиться Ваш вариант.
Напишите, как сохраняется вывод в переменные, чтобы с ними можно было работать дальше. 
Мне ясно, что Ваш вариант проще!

Comment: @volkovsergey: Зачем изобретать велосипед? Используйте [готовую библиотеку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/219399/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-java-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-jsoup), и жизнь станет проще.

Comment: Предложенное регулярное выражение (php) разбивает строку на переменные. Я попросил написать код, как значения попадают в переменные, чтобы можно было работать с ними дальше. Например, $var1, $var2, $var3..., 
Библиотека, на которую мне дали ссылку не уменьшает год парсера. Мой код меньше.

Comment: Кстати, на perl всё ещё проще, но надо на java, но к регулярным выражением это имеет мало отношения.

Comment: @volkovsergey про особенности java не знаю. На перле без проблем могу